# Azure Function App authentication using Azure App Service "Easy Auth"

Tags: authentication, terraform, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Azure Function App for GPG encryption/singing and decryption/verification. This is invoked by Azure Data Factory pipelines to perform GPG operations before subsequent SFTP activities.

For authentication to the Function App (from ADF), I'm currently using Function App keys (or could switch to Function Keys easily enough for finer granularity) and this works well, but should I be using AAD? a.k.a. [Easy Auth with the App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization)

If so, does anyone have some example Terraform scripts for how to do this. There's quite a few auth settings to configure and I haven't come across a **simple** tutorial/example for this. I'm almost thinking that using Function App keys is easier and probably *good enough*. Thoughts?

Comment: Whether or not to use AAD for authentication depends on your specific security requirements and the level of control you need over access to your resources. If Function App keys provide sufficient security for your needs, then they may be a good option. However, if you need more control over access to your resources, then AAD may be a better option.

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!